# Angle of the corner of a triangle when increasing the size of one side.

Tags: geometry

I'm currently working on a project which involves a turning arm, and the best way I can turn it currently (for reasons I won't get into) is essentially by pushing it. I want to make this turning arm turn at a constant rate.

There are two congruent line segments, $A$ and $B$, which are joined at a point. There is also a line connecting the two other ends, $C$. $A$ is stationary and $B$ is free to swing but will stay connected to $A$. $C$ is expanding at a certain, not necessarily constant, rate. As $C$ expands, $B$ is pushed and $\angle AB$ increases. Assuming $\angle AB$ starts at $0$ and ends at $180$ degrees, what function can I apply to a constantly increasing variable, $x$, so that if $C$ is the result, $\angle AB$ increases at a constant rate? In other words, what should $f(x)$ be so that an isosceles triangle where the unique side is the output of $f(x)$ has a linearly increasing angle, which is opposite of the unique side?

Comment: @A Neutrino Boy Thanks I didn't know how to do that and I'll be using that a lot from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your angle between $A$ and $B$ is $\alpha$. If you draw the altitude from the point of intersection of your segments $A$ and $B$ to $C$, you can easily see that the length of $C$ is $2L\sin(\alpha/2)$, where $L$ is the common length of the segments $A$ and $B$. So your function is
$$
f(\alpha)=2L\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right).
$$
When you say that $\alpha$ is increasing at a constant rate, you probably mean that $\alpha=\omega t$, where $\omega$ is a constant angular velocity and $t$ is time. As a function of time, your function is thus
$$
g(t)=2L\sin\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised it was this simple of an equation but so hard for me to figure out!